# Problem with mouseout and looking for alternative to hide() and show()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to create a simple, but large dropdown menu. I have some questions redarding this and hoping to get some help.

First, when I hover with the mouse over the link 'meny_1' with the mouseover() function the submenu 'undermeny_a' displays with the show() function. The submenu is inside a div called 'undermeny_1'. With mouseout() function the div is removed. But if I divide that div into other divs, the mouseout() function will not work. It's like it's not detecting the main div 'undermeny_1' any more? I wonder how to solve this?

Second, I wonder if there are any alternative to use show() and hide(). I want the div element to be in the background above the pages other div element but not visible until i hover the mouse above the link 'meny_1'? In plain javascript I used to use visibility or hidden, something that could be done with jQuery? Hide something without remove the element? Preciate some help. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#meny_1").mouseover(function(){
        $("#underMeny_1").show();
    });
    $("#underMeny_1").mouseout(function(){
        $("#underMeny_1").hide();<br/>
    });<br/> 
});
```

Comment: upload a fiddle so that we could have a look at it....and UNDERSTAND actually what is happening...and what is not

Comment: Have you considered using an existing jquery plugin that does dropdown menus. There are many out there. Writing one from scratch can be extremely fiddly, especially when dealing with keeping the correct divs visible when mouse moves from one submenu to another.

Comment: Well, there is a greater satisfaction to be able to do something on your own. I doesn't need to be as fancy as those that you could download. I'm quite sure it's not that hard to create this type of menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the mouse events, the jQuery API for [mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) shows the difference between mouseleave() and mouseout() that might help you out.

In essence, the mouseenter() / mouseleave() events trigger when the mouse enters or leaves the bounds of the element. Where the mouseover() / mouseout() events trigger whenever the mouse moves from one `<div>` to another.

If I understand your visibility issue, show() and hide() can work the same was as you did before hide(0) will hide the element immediately. Is there a different effect you wanted?

Comment: I'm looking for something like this document.getElementById("div name").style.visibility='visible'; This isn't removing the element, just hide it!

Comment: From what I understand, .hide() shouldn't remove the element. that's what the .remove() or .detach() methods are for. `$("#divId").hide(0);` should set `display: none`.

Comment: From the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/hide/): "The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline."

Answer (score 0):

you can try [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). I am not sure what exaclty you want. toggle() is another available alternative for show() and hide(). which hides a element if it's visible and vice versa

Comment: `toggle()` is not an alternative to `show()` and `hide()` its a function that allows to perform certain operations of our choice on with the toggling effect which need not necessarily be hide/show..and as far as the case of user790843: is concerned this might not be useful

Comment: i agree with @Abdul toggle can contain any effect

Comment: If I'm using toggle() is the elemet just hidden or removed?

Comment: you can use any effect with toggle .check it out [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: @user790843 with toggle() the element is just hidden

Answer (score 0):

You could try with animate / (fadein/fadeout) / fadeout.

Why dosen't the menu remove when you mouseout from the menu, then you could use the .hover() method. And why is it not a ul list?

Comment: The menu is removed, despite that I'm "inside" the div "underMeny_1". It happens when the mouse is over the other div inside the div "underMeny_1". meny_1 is part of a ul list.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your CSS, and not your jQuery, having some problems visualizing what's happening, maybe try uploading your files so we can have a look

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: Hide something without remove the element? 
to hide using jquery you can use $("#div").hide() or $("#div").css("display", "none");

Comment: Hmmm, but isn't $("#div").hide() the same as I have used in my code? That will remove the element? Is there not any method like the old days when you just used document.getElementById("div name").style.visibility='visible'; ??

Comment: .hide() will not remove the element. it will only set its style (display:none) thus hiding it.
.hide() is like .style.visibility , but instead style.display .. read about it

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a fade effect, then you can go with fadein/fadeout in place of show/hide.

However if all you want is to do visibility hidden, and no effect then, In place of show/hide I personally prefer to create a hide css class like this.

```
.hide{display:none; !important}
```

and then use .addClass(hide) / .removeClass(hide)

more details at http://www.nitinh.com/2011/05/how-to-properly-hide-and-show-elements-using-javascript/

Regarding you first point, I am not sure if I understood it correctly. It'd be better if you could give us a demo link.